# multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: 'TypeError("cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object",)'

Tags: python, multiprocessing, urllib, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

Why does the code below work only with `multiprocessing.dummy`, but not with simple `multiprocessing`.

```
import urllib.request
#from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool #this works
from multiprocessing import Pool

urls = ['http://www.python.org', 'http://www.yahoo.com','http://www.scala.org', 'http://www.google.com']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        results = p.map(urllib.request.urlopen, urls)
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urlthreads.py", line 31, in <module>
    results = p.map(urllib.request.urlopen, urls)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\patri\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x0000016AEF204198>]'. Reason: 'TypeError("cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object")'
```

What's missing so that it works without "dummy" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `http.client.HTTPResponse`-object you get back from `urlopen()` has a `_io.BufferedReader`-object attached, and this object cannot be pickled.

```
pickle.dumps(urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org').fp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    pickle.dumps(urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org').fp)
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object
```

`multiprocessing.Pool` will need to pickle (serialize) the results to send it back to the parent process and this fails here. Since `dummy` uses threads instead of processes, there will be no pickling, because threads in the same process share their memory naturally.

A general solution to this `TypeError` is:

1. read out the buffer and save the content (if needed)
2. remove the reference to `'_io.BufferedReader'` from the object you are trying to pickle

In your case, calling `.read()` on the `http.client.HTTPResponse` will empty and remove the buffer, so a function for converting the response into something pickleable could simply do this:

```
def read_buffer(response):
    response.text = response.read()
    return response
```

Example:

```
r = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org')
r = read_buffer(r)
pickle.dumps(r)
# Out: b'\x80\x03chttp.client\nHTTPResponse\...
```

Before you consider this approach, make sure you really want to use multiprocessing instead of multithreading. For I/O-bound tasks like you have it here, multithreading would be sufficient, since most of the time is spend in waiting (no need for cpu-time) for the response anyway. Multiprocessing and the IPC involved also introduces substantial overhead.