# How to fix "TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object" when writing pandas dataframe to_pickle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pickle

I have a simple code where I am reading an excel .xlsx file as a dataframe and then writing it back as a pickle file using *to_pickle*. I have been using the same code for months to read and write as new excel files arrive. However, this time when I tried my code it is giving me **TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object** error for some reason. Here is the code,

```
# Path to .xlsx
MasterItem = MonthlyFolder + "MasterItem__Nov2019.xlsx"

# Function to read the excel file
def ReadExcel(filename, sheetname=None, header=0):
    from openpyxl import load_workbook

    wb = load_workbook(filename, read_only=True)

    if sheetname is None:  # If sheetname is not provided then grab the first sheet
        print("\t Reading " + wb.sheetnames[0])
        ws = wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]
    else:
        print("\t Reading " + sheetname)
        ws = wb[sheetname]

    data = ws.values

    if header is None:
        columns = None
    elif header > 0:
        # Skip non header rows
        for i in range(0, header):
            next(data)
        # Save header row
        columns = next(data)[0:]
    else:
        columns = next(data)[0:]

    # Create a DataFrame based on the subsequent lines of data
    df_Out = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

    return df_Out

# Reading .xlsx and writing as pickle
RawMasterItem = ReadExcel(MasterItem)
pd.to_pickle(RawMasterItem, MonthlyFolder+"RawMasterItem.pkl") # This fails to run
```

Following is the output and error I am getting,

```
    ../Data/2019Nov/MasterItem__Nov2019.xlsx
         Reading Sheet1
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Eulhaq\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\DataScience\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
      File "<ipython-input-10-07041bb51f98>", line 3, in <module>
        pd.to_pickle(RawMasterItem, MonthlyFolder+"RawMasterItem.pkl")
      File "C:\Users\Eulhaq\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\DataScience\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 76, in to_pickle
        f.write(pickle.dumps(obj, protocol=protocol))
    TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object
```

Comment: I know the error from [multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54737201/9059420). You need to find and remove (emptying might suffice) the buffer , but I can't tell you where it sits in your case. Must be a leftover from reading in the Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

So after whole day of debugging it turns out that for some **blank cells** in my excel file, openpyxl is returning `<ReadOnlyCell 'Sheet1'.D2>` object. This cell is further creating problems when I try to write the dataframe as pickle. Even though the data type of the columns is 'str' but when I explicitly changed the datatype again to 'str', it solved the problem.

```
RawMasterItem['Column'] = RawMasterItem['Column'].astype('str')
```

Apparently, instead of reading and returning nulls/blanks properly, openpyxl is returning some weird objects, which is subsequently not serializable.